# appscript api invalid content

Tags: api, google-apps-script, whatsapp

i'm trying to use whatsapp api from https://whapi.io/

using postman it show no error
[result using postman success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjbzf.png)

but when I try to use in googlesheet appscript by creating custom function

```
function whatsappSend() {
  var myHeaders = {
      "contentType": "application/json"
    }

  var raw = JSON.stringify({
    "app": {
      "id": "601154119177", //sender@api_key
      "time": "1646716022", //sample_data
      "data": {
        "recipient": {
          "id": "60133102649" //recipient number with country code
        },
        "message": [
          {
            "time": "1646716022",
            "type": "text",
            "value": "Hello World!11"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  });

  var requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: myHeaders,
    body: raw,
    redirect: 'follow'
  };

  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://whapi.io/api/send", requestOptions);
  console.log(res.toString())
  
}
```

it show invalid-content

```
{"msg":"invalid content","result":"error"}
```

So how to create working appscript function, for sending using this api?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

From [this document](https://whapi.io/docs), how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function whatsappSend() {
  var raw = JSON.stringify({
    "app": {
      "id": "601154119177", //sender@api_key
      "time": "1646716022", //sample_data
      "data": {
        "recipient": {
          "id": "60133102649" //recipient number with country code
        },
        "message": [
          {
            "time": "1646716022",
            "type": "text",
            "value": "Hello World!11"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  });
  var requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json",
    payload: raw,
  };
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://whapi.io/api/send", requestOptions);
  console.log(res.getContentText())
}
```

#### Note:

- If an error occurs, please confirm the values of `raw` again.

#### Reference:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)